# É possível fazer um INSERT e um UPDATE em uma mesma query no java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um `INSERT` e um `UPDATE` na mesma query, ou seja, na mesma operação.

Estou usando o seguinte para fazer as duas operações.

```
public Connection conn = null;
...
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName,password);
...

String Query_SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE users SET name = 'exemplo';";
String Query_SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO `users_logs` (user_id, name) VALUES ('1','demo');";

PreparedStatement Update_SQL = conn.prepareStatement(Query_SQL_UPDATE);
                  Update_SQL.execute();
PreparedStatement Insert_SQL = conn.prepareStatement(Query_SQL_INSERT);
                  Insert_SQL.execute();
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso, ou até simplificar esses comandos? Se sim, quais são.

Comment: Já que está utilizando query livre. Imagino que se botar um ";" e a segunda instrução, funcione.

Comment: Parece que não há  nada na documentação do JDBC dizendo que não pode reaproveitar, inclusive já fiz algo parecido(insert seguido de select) e não tive problemas. No caso de Statement, pode reaproveitar sem problemas, mas se precisar de retorno, o resultset não é reaproveitavel.

Comment: @mauhumor já havia tentado, porem sem sucesso, o motivo eu não sei. Vamos esperar alguma resposta e ver se da certo diegofm

Comment: @Florida o jeito que fiz foi passando a primeira query, mandando executar, depois passando a segunda query pro mesmo statement e executando de novo. Mandar as duas juntas de uma vez eu não sei se é possivel(nem recomendavel).

Comment: Então imagino que não de para fazer isso, pois são operações diferentes. Não vejo problema nenhum do jeito que você está fazendo. Talvez, para manter integridade, caso a uma das operações falhe, seria bom utilizar transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. E existem duas maneiras de fazê-lo.

A **primeira** é através da inserção dessas queries em uma SP (Stored Procedure).

Dessa forma basta chamar a SP com os parâmetros e praticamente qualquer sequência de procedimentos poderá ser realizada no banco de dados.

Mais informações sobre a criação de SPs para MySql podem ser vistas [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

A **segunda** opção (e acho que é a mais conveniente para o seu caso) é alterar a *string* de conexão com o banco de dados para permitir múltiplas queries. Se isso não for feito, uma *exception* será invariavelmente lançada:

```
String dbStringConn = "jdbc:mysql:///bancodados?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

Após configurar corretamente a *url* de conexão, basta chamar o método `execute(query)`. Seu código ficaria algo como:

```
String query = "UPDATE users SET name = 'exemplo'; INSERT INTO `users_logs` (user_id, name) VALUES ('1','demo');";

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.execute();
```

Repare que as queries estão separadas por **;** (ponto e vírgula).

Mais detalhes sobre os parâmetros permitidos na *url* de conexão com MySql através do driver JDBC podem ser consultados [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: Não tinha observado isso do `allowMultiQueries=true`, mais tarde vou tentar usando ele.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada depois de sua pergunta e achei algumas informações sobre outra opção `addBatch`, `executeBatch` se pudesse enriquecer a resposta com esse outro método, acredito que é o que falta para uma resposta ser aceita. `:)`

Comment: addBatch e executeBatch são relacionadas a execução de uma mesma query múltiplas vezes. Por exemplo, quando desejamos realizar 3000 inserções no banco de dados, chamamos isso de batch (lote) de execuções. A sua dúvida se refere a execução de múltiplas queries, e não de uma única query múltiplas vezes. Então para esse caso, addBatch e executeBatch fogem do escopo da pergunta. Um exemplo pode ser visto aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Isso independe da linguagem de programação.
Até onde sei, os banco de dados (relacionais, pelo menos) não aceitam fazer mais de uma query ao mesmo tempo (salvo subqueries, mas aí é apenas para select).
Você pode utilizar uma `transaction` e realizar uma série de consultas que alteram valores e depois realizar o `commit`.

Me corrija se estiver errado, mas lendo o seu código entendi que você quer "logar" toda alteração feita, certo?
Existem formas melhores de se fazer isso, mas na sua implementação, você poderia externalizar isso em um método do seu `dao` genérico e utilizar `transaction` para garantir que as duas informações sejam persistidas (tanto a alteração dos dados como o registro do log). Dessa forma, sempre que executar um `update`, por exemplo, você garante que vai registrar o log.

---

**Atenção:** fazer `insert into x values(1,2,3); update tabela set col = 1;` não representa uma única query.
São duas queries diferentes.
O Banco executa uma depois a outra.
A query é definida até o `;` ou até onde o SGDB entende que a query vai (falta do `;`).
Ao fazer assim **sem** `transaction` você corre o risco de executar uma query e não executar a outra.